# add margin to a programatically added view

Tags: java, android

I'm adding the same view programtically into a gridLayout everytime I click a button, I want to set a margin to those added views, how do I do it?
I've tried `layoutParams.setMargin(10,10,10,10)` and `theLayout.setPadding(10,10,10,10)`

Here's how I'm adding the views:

```
        gridLayout= (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gamehistory);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Button theButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                TextView theText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                theText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

                LinearLayout theLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                theLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                theLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8BAAC3"));
                theLayout.setId(++i);
                theText.setText(theLayout.getId() + "");
                theLayout.addView(theButton);
                theLayout.addView(theText);
                gridLayout.addView(theLayout, layoutParams);
            }
        });
```

EDIT: I set the LayoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams, because it doesn't accept GirdLayout.LayoutParams and it doesn't seem to affect it.

What I need is a way to add a margin to the linear layout I'm continually adding with the button (theLayout).

Comment: So you're trying to add the margin to which view?  The LinearLayout?

Comment: Actually, I'm confused.  You have a GridLayout whose variable name is linearLayout.  Please be specific about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding to the gridLayout and reusing the same layout parameters each time like you are now:

```
gridLayout.addView(theLayout, layoutParams);
```

You can simply accept that GridLayout will assign a new layout parameters object to each child ([addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) will create it for you), and you can modify that directly instead:

```
gridLayout.addView(theLayout);
GridLayout.LayoutParams lp = (GridLayout.LayoutParams) theLayout.getLayoutParams();
lp.setMargins(...)
```

Comment: I can't try it right now, but it looks like it will work, so I will confindently accept your answer :)